# openssl s_client -showcerts -servername xyz -connect xyz:443 hangs for a long time

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

On Ubuntu I am using:

```
$ openssl s_client -showcerts -servername myhost -connect myhost:443 | openssl x509 --enddate --noout
depth=2 ...
verify return:1
depth=1 ...
verify return:1
depth=0 ...
verify return:1
notAfter=Aug 11 10:56:02 2036 GMT
```

to check e.g. expiration dates for certificates. But for some reason it hangs for a long time - some times up to a minute - even though the results are returned immediately.

Is there a way to avoid this wait and just terminate after the result has been printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`openssl s_client` is designed to be interactive and by default, it is waiting for your input. So you should either have `echo |` in front, or `</dev/null` after the command.

Additionally, you could also add a timeout in case a server cannot be reached.

This is how I do it in a script which verifies dates on different servers and services:

```
timeout $timeout \
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect $server:$port </dev/null 2>/dev/null \
| openssl x509 -noout -subject -dates
```